# How to compute the rank of a vector in C?

Tags: c

How can one (efficiently/quickly) determine the ranking of (elements of) a vector in C (not C++ or using non-standard libraries)? For example, the rank(ing) of the vector `x=(0.25, 0.54, 0.38, 0.32, 0.49, 0.06, 0.41, 0.21, 0.98, 0.23)` should be `rank(x)=(4, 9, 6, 5, 8, 1, 7, 2, 10, 3)`.

As the name suggests, the 'ranking' gives the rank of each element of the vector in relation to all other elements of the vector. So `rank(x[k])=l` means that the `k`th element of `x` is the `l`th smallest among all elements in `x` (e.g., for `k=6` in the above example, `l` is 1, i.e., the 6th element of x is the smallest). Note that such a function `rank()` exists in several other programming languages, but I haven't seen a C implementation yet. What I'm looking for is a pure C implementation which works as fast as possible for vectors of integers or real numbers.

Comment: *haha*, nice comment... thanks. I'll update it soon.

Comment: Sort the values, their position will be their *rank - 1*, use [`qsort(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html)

Comment: ... sure, but qsort doesn't allow to pass a second vector (of indices) which are then operated on accordingly... Also, I'm not a good C programmer, I wanted to learn from more experienced C users here how to do that. I could imagine you define some sort of struct and work on that...

Comment: Why do you need a second vector of indices, you need the ranks to be in the original positions where the values were?

Comment: well... as I said, I'm not an expert here (which is why I didn't provide a MWE)... whatever solves the problem is good with me.

Comment: No, no one will give you any code like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it is to pair up your data with indexes, sort using `qsort` and a comparator that checks only the value and ignores the index, and then assign ranks according to sorted indexes.

Here is an implementation that `malloc`s the temporary array of pairs, rather than using automatic storage. This is safer in cases when the amount of data is large enough to overrun the stack.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct rank_pair {
    double val;
    size_t ind;
};

int cmp_rank_pair(const void* a, const void* b) {
    struct rank_pair *lhs = (struct rank_pair*)a;
    struct rank_pair *rhs = (struct rank_pair*)b;
    return lhs->val < rhs->val ? -1 : (lhs->val > rhs->val ? 1 : 0);
}

void rank(double a[], int r[], size_t n) {
    struct rank_pair *tmp = malloc(n*sizeof(struct rank_pair));
    for (int i = 0 ; i != n ; i++) {
        tmp[i].val = a[i];
        tmp[i].ind = i;
    }
    qsort(tmp, n, sizeof(struct rank_pair), cmp_rank_pair);
    for (int i = 0 ; i != n ; i++) {
        r[tmp[i].ind] = i+1;
    }
    free(tmp);
}

int main(void) {
    const size_t N = 10;
    double a[] = {0.25, 0.54, 0.38, 0.32, 0.49, 0.06, 0.41, 0.21, 0.98, 0.23};
    int r[N];
    rank(a, r, N);
    for (int i = 0 ; i != N ; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", r[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Fe7Pww)

Comment: Thanks for helping, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @rcgldr Sorting an array of indexes on values is a little tricky to do with `qsort`, because its comparator is a plain function. `qsort_r` would do the trick, but it is not standard. Static variable would be another way to go, but it makes for a solution that's not re-entrant. Array of pointers solves this problem, but I figured that if I am making an auxiliary array anyway, I might as well show how to do it with an array of pairs.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Yes, the indices would be an issue, so the array of pointers would be an alternate method to produce the rank. For a large array, a counting / radix sort by byte (4 passes for 32 bit values, 8 passes for 64 bit values) should be faster (the OP mentioned as fast as possible). For signed integers or reals, the sign bit needs to be toggled when using the most significant byte for indexing purposes (assuming the byte is treated as unsigned).

Comment: @rcgldr I take "as fast as possible" with a grain of salt, especially when the question does not provide a working "reference solution" that has an unacceptable timing. All they really want is "really, really fast", not "optimized-to-death-fast". In situations like that, providing a simple O(N*LogN) solution may be better, especially when it teaches readers a new reusable skill.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - forgot to mention, the paired method with a copy of the values and generated indices may be faster due to cache locality (assuming qsort is cache friendly). Using an array of pointers would end up doing a lot of memory random access on the original array of values.